# Scalar curvature in terms of structure constants

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm currently reading this  [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.04454.pdf). The part I'm interested in is the one where they compute the riemann tensor and ricci tensor in terms of the structure constants (page 3). First of all, where is $g([e_i, ej], e_k) = C_{ijk}$ coming from? I'm aware of this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993200/are-christoffel-symbols-structure-coefficients) but I just cant figure it out.. might be super obvious :/

Then they compute the riemann tensor with $R(e_i, e_j, e_h, e_i)$ and I'm not so sure about this notion since with my definition I would start like $R(e_i, e_j, e_k)$ since it is (1,3) tensor and takes only 3 vectors..? and for the ricci tensor the only difference is that we sum over i now? Could someone help me out here so I can try to compute the scalar curvature as well? And what is this well known identity $tr \space ad [e_i, e_j] = 0$ ? Is there any literature on structure constants?

Thank you so much for any help!

Best,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer at your second link uses $$g([E_i,\,E_j],\,E_k)=g(C_{ijl}E^l,\,E_k)=C_{ijl}\delta_k^l=C_{ijk}$$to prove$$\Gamma_{ijk}=C_{ijk}+C_{kij}+C_{kji}.$$[Hence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Coordinate_expression)$$\begin{align}R^e_{\:bcd}&=(\partial_c\Gamma^e_{db}+\Gamma^e_{cf}\Gamma^f_{bd})-c\leftrightarrow d\\\implies R_{abcd}&=(g_{ae}\partial_c(g^{eg}\Gamma_{gdb})+g^{fg}\Gamma_{acf}\Gamma_{gbd})-c\leftrightarrow d\\&=(g_{ae}\Gamma_{gdb}\partial_cg^{eg}+\partial_c\Gamma_{adb}+g^{fg}\Gamma_{acf}\Gamma_{gbd})-c\leftrightarrow d.\end{align}$$Freel free to rewrite the Christoffel symbols in that result in terms of structure constants.

Since $[E_a,\,E_b]=C_{abc}E^c$ and $\partial_d(E_aE_b)=g_{da}E_b+g_{db}E_a$ is $a\leftrightarrow b$-symmetric,$$0=\partial_d(C_{abc}E^c)=E^c\partial_dC_{abc}+C_{abd}\implies\partial_dC_{abc}=-\frac1nE_cC_{abd}$$in an $n$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Ah this makes a lot more sense now! Thank you

However, for the second part if I rewrite it in terms of structure constants I end up with partial deriv. of the C's.. How could I start using the levi civita connection in terms of structure constants as they did in the paper?

Comment: @Cutcher See edit.

Comment: could you quickly explain the term $\partial _d (E_a E_b)$ and what you do with it? It looks to me were "multiplying" two vectors which means this is the lie bracket? So is it the partial derivative of the lie bracket? but where is this g coming from on the rhs.. feels like I need some literature on this topic